# How to filter by issues created by GitHub App using their GraphQL API?

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I'm trying to migrate from GitHub's REST API to their GraphQL API in my GitHub bot. I want to filter open issues created by my bot on [this repository](https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc).

I've tried the following queries:

```
query ListOpenIssues {
  repository(name: "pacstall-programs", owner: "pacstall") {
    issues(last: 100, filterBy: {states: OPEN, createdBy: "app/pacstall-pacbot"}) {
      nodes {
        number
        title
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
query ListOpenIssues {
  repository(name: "pacstall-programs", owner: "pacstall") {
    issues(last: 100, filterBy: {states: OPEN, createdBy: "pacstall-pacbot"}) {
      nodes {
        number
        title
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But both of them return

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "issues": {
        "nodes": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How do I properly filter the issues created by my bot?

PS: I've seen this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940105/filter-github-issues-by-author-using-their-graphql-api), but it was created 3 years ago, and since then GitHub's GraphQL API has changed, and supports the `createdBy` field to filter issues.

Comment: Hi, I tried the GitHub Graphql explorer using the below query and I am getting result.query ListOpenIssues {
  repository(name: "SerilogWithNet6", owner: "chinmaywindows") {
    issues(last: 100, filterBy: {states: OPEN, createdBy: "chinmaywindows"}) {
      nodes {
        number
        title
        url
      }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from @Chinmay T's answer and comments:

```
query ListOpenIssues {
  repository(name: "pacstall-programs", owner: "pacstall") {
    issues(last: 100, filterBy: {states: OPEN, labels: ["major update", "minor update", "patch update"]}) {
      nodes {
        number
        title
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
```

is a workaround for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to GitHub support, the solution is to append "[bot]" to *author* fields when filtering:

```
query ListOpenIssues {
  repository(name: "pacstall-programs", owner: "pacstall") {
    issues(last: 3, filterBy: {createdBy: "pacstall-pacbot[bot]"}) {
      nodes {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have asked GH support to update the documentation as this is not mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

I tried GitHub GraphQL explorer and the below query simply works for me. The only difference here is the user account is not a bot user. I believe you might need to check the user profile of the bot.

Here is the link for GitHub GraphQL explorer [link](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer)

```
query ListOpenIssues {
  repository(name: "SerilogWithNet6", owner: "chinmaywindows") {
    issues(last: 100, filterBy: {states: OPEN, createdBy: "chinmaywindows"}) {
      nodes {
        number
        title
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

This is how it is looking on the GitHub.

[image]

This is the query on your repository without created by filter and I am getting bot details.

[image]

Try this query, I believe I am getting the right results.

```
  query ListOpenIssues {
  repository(name: "pacstall-programs", owner: "pacstall") {
    issues(last: 50, filterBy: {states: OPEN}) {
      nodes {
        number
        title
        url
        author {
          ... on User {
            id
            email
            issues(last: 50, filterBy: {createdBy: "pacstall-pacbot"}) {
              edges {
                node {
                  id
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

The result set of the above query.

```
    {
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "issues": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "number": 2615,
            "title": "Outdated `signal-desktop-deb`: `6.1.0` -> `6.13.0`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2615",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2654,
            "title": "Outdated `yt-dlp`: `2023.02.17` -> `2023.03.04`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2654",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2662,
            "title": "Outdated `pycharm-community-bin`: `2022.3.2` -> `2022.3.3`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2662",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2664,
            "title": "Outdated `gtkmm4`: `4.8.0` -> `4.10.0`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2664",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2667,
            "title": "Outdated `protonmail-bridge-deb`: `3.0.19` -> `3.0.20`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2667",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2669,
            "title": "PacReq: VirtualBox 7",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2669",
            "author": {
              "id": "MDQ6VXNlcjczNzM0ODQz",
              "email": "anifyuliansyah@gmail.com",
              "issues": {
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "number": 2680,
            "title": "PacReq: schildichat-desktop",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2680",
            "author": {
              "id": "MDQ6VXNlcjQxNjMxNDI1",
              "email": "",
              "issues": {
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "number": 2698,
            "title": "Outdated `1password-cli-bin`: `2.13.1` -> `2.15.0`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2698",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2699,
            "title": "Outdated `opera-beta-deb`: `94.0.4606.19` -> `96.0.4693.80`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2699",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2707,
            "title": "Outdated `plexmediaserver-deb`: `1.27.1.5916-6b0e31a64` -> `1.31.2.6810`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2707",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2719,
            "title": "Outdated `expressvpn-deb`: `3.38.0.3-1` -> `11.23.0.73611`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2719",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2720,
            "title": "Outdated `aws-cli-v2-bin`: `2.9.11` -> `2.11.4`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2720",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2722,
            "title": "Outdated `chezmoi-deb`: `2.31.1` -> `2.32.0`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2722",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2724,
            "title": "Outdated `onlyoffice-desktopeditors-deb`: `7.3.0` -> `7.3.3`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2724",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2726,
            "title": "Outdated `hyperfine-bin`: `1.15.0` -> `1.16.0`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2726",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2728,
            "title": "Use github actions to automatically generate packagelist",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2728",
            "author": {
              "id": "MDQ6VXNlcjgzMjE3Mjc2",
              "email": "",
              "issues": {
                "edges": []
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "number": 2734,
            "title": "Outdated `oil`: `0.14.1` -> `0.14.2`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2734",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2737,
            "title": "Outdated `brave-browser-beta-deb`: `1.49.108` -> `1.50.94`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2737",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2740,
            "title": "Outdated `chwp-deb`: `1.187.0` -> `1.193.0`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2740",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2741,
            "title": "Outdated `discord-ptb-deb`: `0.0.38` -> `0.0.41`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2741",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2742,
            "title": "Outdated `dust-bin`: `0.8.4` -> `0.8.5`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2742",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2743,
            "title": "Outdated `electronmail-deb`: `5.1.2` -> `5.1.6`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2743",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2744,
            "title": "Outdated `element-desktop-deb`: `1.11.24` -> `1.11.25`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2744",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2746,
            "title": "Outdated `firefox-developer-edition-bin`: `111.0b5` -> `112.0b3`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2746",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2747,
            "title": "Outdated `git`: `2.37.1` -> `2.40.0`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2747",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2748,
            "title": "Outdated `git-credential-manager-core-deb`: `2.0.785` -> `2.0.935`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2748",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2749,
            "title": "Outdated `github-cli-bin`: `2.22.1` -> `2.24.3`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2749",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2750,
            "title": "Outdated `github-cli-deb`: `2.21.1` -> `2.24.3`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2750",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2751,
            "title": "Outdated `gitkraken-deb`: `9.1.1` -> `9.2.1`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2751",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2752,
            "title": "Outdated `go-bin`: `1.20.1` -> `1.20.2`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2752",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2753,
            "title": "Outdated `google-chrome-beta-deb`: `111.0.5563.41` -> `112.0.5615.29`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2753",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2754,
            "title": "Outdated `google-chrome-deb`: `110.0.5481.177` -> `113.0.5653.0`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2754",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2755,
            "title": "Outdated `google-chrome-unstable-deb`: `112.0.5596.2` -> `113.0.5653.0`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2755",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2756,
            "title": "Outdated `librewolf-app`: `110.0-2` -> `111.0-2`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2756",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2757,
            "title": "Outdated `mcontrolcenter-bin`: `0.3.2` -> `0.4.0`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2757",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2758,
            "title": "Outdated `microsoft-edge-dev-deb`: `112.0.1698.0` -> `112.0.1722.7`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2758",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2759,
            "title": "Outdated `microsoft-edge-stable-deb`: `110.0.1587.50` -> `111.0.1661.44`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2759",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2760,
            "title": "Outdated `mullvad-vpn-beta-deb`: `2022.3-beta3` -> `2023.2`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2760",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2761,
            "title": "Outdated `mullvad-vpn-deb`: `2023.1` -> `2023.2`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2761",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2762,
            "title": "Outdated `nordlayer-deb`: `2.6.0` -> `2.7.0`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2762",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2763,
            "title": "Outdated `nushell-bin`: `0.76.0` -> `0.77.1`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2763",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2764,
            "title": "Outdated `postman-bin`: `10.11.1` -> `10.12.0`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2764",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2765,
            "title": "Outdated `rstudio-deb`: `2022.12.0.353` -> `2023.03.0.386`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2765",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2766,
            "title": "Outdated `signal-desktop-beta-deb`: `6.2.0-beta.2` -> `6.11.0beta2`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2766",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2767,
            "title": "Outdated `spotify-client-deb`: `1.1.84.716.gc5f8b819-2` -> `1.2.7.1277`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2767",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2769,
            "title": "Outdated `topgrade-musl-bin`: `10.2.4` -> `10.3.3`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2769",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2770,
            "title": "Outdated `tutanota-app`: `3.106.4` -> `3.110.1`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2770",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2771,
            "title": "Outdated `yandex-browser-stable-deb`: `22.5.3.673-1` -> `23.1.5.751_1`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2771",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2772,
            "title": "Outdated `zotero`: `6.0.22` -> `6.0.23`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2772",
            "author": {}
          },
          {
            "number": 2774,
            "title": "Outdated `opera-developer-deb`: `96.0.4640.0` -> `98.0.4739.0`",
            "url": "https://github.com/pacstall/pacstall-programs/issues/2774",
            "author": {}
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "The only difference here is the user account is not a bot user."



That's my sole problem. I can't get it to return open issues created by the bot as detailed in my question.

Comment: Please verify the result set, I check the top 10 issues and it is showing the correct result.

Comment: Sorry, I believe issues #2680 and 2728 were created by users. I believe you need to filter the result after getting the API results. You can assign a new tag 'created-by-bot' and easily filter by tags.